# More Satisfying Proofs for the Chain Rule for Fréchet Derivatives

Tags: calculus

I am looking for some proofs for the chain rule of Fréchet derivatives. The only arguments I have seen so far always involved using a linear approximation.

E.g. Let $ f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to V \subset \mathbb{R}^m $ and $ g : V \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to W \subset \mathbb{R}^p $ be smooth maps. Then $g\circ f : U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to W\subset\mathbb{R}^p$. If we accept that for any smooth map $\phi$,

$$ 
\phi(p+v) \approx \phi(p) + (D\phi)_p(v)
$$

then

$$
(g\circ f)(p) + \left(D(g\circ f)\right)_p(v) \approx (g\circ f)(p+v) = g(f(p+v)) 
\\
\approx g( f(p) + (Df)_p(v)) \approx g(f(p))+(Dg)_{f(p)}\left((Df)_p(v)\right)
\\
= (g\circ f)(p) + \left((Dg)_{f(p)}\circ (Df)_p\right)(v) 
$$

So $ (D(g\circ f))_p(v) \approx \left((Dg)_{f(p)}\circ (Df)_p\right)(v) $ and equality occurs when $||v||\to 0$.

This feels somehow unsatisfying because of the number of appoximate signs (does not feel like maths!) and using a linear approximation invokes multivariate Taylor’s theorem. I guess you can say that I am looking for some elementary proofs.